# ¿Cual es el EOF o \0 en python?

Tags: python

Quiero recorrer cada linea de mi archivo hasta un determinado punto que sería el final del archivo y no se en python hasta que caracter sería o como puedo hacer para que me recorra todo el archivo.

Estoy guardando cada linea que hay en mi archivo en una variable.

```
linea= archivo.readline()
```

El problema es que me gustaría recorrerlo con un ciclo como en otros lenguajes hasta el final del archivo y no se como hacerlo en este lenguaje.

```py
def informe(archivo):
    suma=0
    i=0
    for line in archivo.readline():
        print(line)
    print("finalizado")
```

Answer (score 2):

El código

```
for line in archivo.readline():
    print(line)
```

lee la primera línea del archivo, cicla a través de sus caracteres y termina, sin procesar el resto.

La forma estándar de procesar un archivo línea por línea en Python es:

```
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    print(linea)
```

La función `readlines()` (plural) es un iterador: devuelve una línea a la vez. Luego de leer la última línea, el método `readlines` genera una excepción `StopIteration`, lo que termina el `for`. Se comporta como si `readlines` devolviera una lista completa, excepto que en realidad va devolviendo línea por línea, lo cual consume menos memoria.

Las líneas devueltas por `readline` y `readlines` incluyen el caracter new-line '\n' al final.

Cuando usas `readline` para tratar de leer pasada la última línea, obtienes un string vacio (sin '\n'), lo que te señala el fin de archivo.

Comment: Excelente!. Muchas gracias!.